# Sidebar missing in Xcode 9, also cannot run iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have a couple questions regarding Xcode 9 which I just upgraded to. The first is, where is the sidebar where you choose what objects to put on the storyboard and set attributes? Xcode 8 had a thingy in the top right where you could toggle it but I can't find it in 9.

Also, whenever I try to run my project it says "A build only device cannot be used to run this target; No supported iOS devices available". In 8 I could see what device was running at the top, but that is now missing.

Additionally, is there a way to force it to open in new window instead of tabs? Xcode 8 opened files in windows and I prefer that to tabs.

I've already updated Cocoapods and deleted the derived data folder, which didn't work.

[image: This is how my Xcode looks. Compared to 8 it's like the entire top bar is missing.]

Comment: I was able to open the project and get the normal view if I opened the Xcode file, however opening the cocoa pods workspace file causes it to look like the picture above. It appears to be an issue with CocoaPods. Anybody know a workaround?

Comment: Are you in fullscreen mode? I got that button on right-top corner. Or use `command` + `option` + `0`(zero) to open/close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try command-option-T (View>Show/Hide Toolbar). Your toolbar is hidden in that image.

For tabs, I think this is what you're referring to. Change the dropdowns if you're seeing tabs instead of new windows when you navigate.[image: Xcode>Preferences>Navigation]

Comment: This fixed everything. Thanks!